# how to style an iframe scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, scrollbar

There is an iframe on my page, and i want to reduce it's scrollbar's width.
This is my code looks like

```
<Row>
              `<CardContent>
                <CardContentItem>
                    <iframe
                    title={" "}
                    style={{ height: "90vh", width: "100%", overflow: "auto" }}
                    srcDoc={String(modalContent)}
                    />
                </CardContentItem>
              </CardContent>`
</Row>
```

I already tried define an iframeStyle and give this as a style to my iframe.

```
// const iframeStyle = {
  //   height: "80vh",
  //   width: "100%",
  //   overflow: "auto",
  //   "::-webkit-scrollbar": {
  //     width: "5px",
  //   },
  //   "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
  //     backgroundColor: "#888",
  //   },
  // };
```

Also, tried scrollbarWidth: "thin".
Can anyone help me please?